# creating and zipping a file

Tags: php, zip

how can i create a zip directory and create a file into it.I tried but don't know how can i zip but i am able to create a directory and a create a new file in it.

Code:

```
$directoryPath = "../word_plugin/".mobilesplash_. time(). _ .$c_id. _plugin;
mkdir($directoryPath);

$myFile = "$directoryPath/testFile.php";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Yoo";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Hello";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);  
fclose($fh);
```

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: It would appear you have not even tried a basic search on how to create a zip file with PHP. This question shows no research effort

Comment: PHP ZipArchive should be some tutorials is you search for it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is easily available in the [manual](http://us2.php.net/zip).

Comment: i tried ZipArchive but it says ZipArchive not found

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZipArchive class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)! Or [RarArchive class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php)

[All available libraries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php)